# Capturing a frame from the webcam into a bitmap - VFW - WINAPI

Tags: c++, c, winapi, bitmap, vfw

I would like to capture a frame from the webcam and get it into a bitmap, I don't want the program to show any window but I am struggling to understand the concept of the vfw functions.

The `capCreateCaptureWindow` is a function that creates the handler to the window of the camera but the function opens a window that allows me to choose camera devices.

My goal is to be able to go through all camera devices, take a picture from them and get them into a bitmap.

Is there a way to do that without using the `capCreateCaptureWindow` function and obtain the device's details through code?

Comment: The DirectShow API can do it, I'm not sure about VFW, which is incredibly outdated.

Comment: What are your minimum target platform requirements? Things have gotten significantly easier with the Windows Runtime in Windows 10 (see [`MediaCapture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture) for example).

Answer (score 0):

First you could try to use [Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wia/-wia-startpage) to get still images from the device. You could also try to use [DirectShow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/directshow) to capture an image.

And then you could [Capturing an Image From a Still Image Pin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/capturing-an-image-from-a-still-image-pin)

Comment: @Omer Friedlander 
Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.